# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ENDPOINT_PROVIDER at software.amazon.awssdk.services.iottwinmaker.DefaultIoTTwinMakerBaseClientBuilde

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I am trying to create a TwimMakerCleint in java, I am using the maven dependency as follows

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/software.amazon.awssdk/iottwinmaker -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>iottwinmaker</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.39</version>
    </dependency>
```

and the snippet to create the connection is

```
IoTTwinMakerClient awsIoTTwinMaker = IoTTwinMakerClient.create();
```

while executing the above line getting the following exception

[image]